# Java Abstraction and Generic Types

Tags: java, generics, abstraction

I'm having a problem properly implementing generics in abstract classes that need to be overridden.

```
public abstract class AbstractSerachView {
    DataStore<AbstractCriteria, AbstractResults, AbstractService> resultsStore;
    public abstract DataStore<AbstractCriteria, AbstractResults, AbstractService> getResultsStore();
}
```

the child clases is as follows:

```
public class TravelSearchView extends AbstractSearchView {
    DataStore<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService> resultsStore;
    public DataStore<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService> getResultsStore() {
        return resultsStore;
    }
}
```

This sort of abstraction does not work at all, although it would be greatly appreciated if I could get this work in some way.  What is the correct approach here?  I have very little experience with generic types.

The problem is that Eclipse indicates an error in the child class: The return type is incompatible with AbstractSearchView.getResultsStore()

Furthermore, if I leave the child class get method with the 3 abstract types, and override the variable with the 3 travel types, everything is okay except for the return line, where Eclipse indicates: Type mismatch:  Cannot convert from DataStore to DataStore

Comment: Is `TravelSearchView` supposed to extend `AbstractSearchView`?

Comment: Yes, and now it does.   TravelCriteria extends AbstractCriteria, TravelResults extends AbstractResults, and TravelService extends AbstractService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your alternatives:

a)  Change the superclass type signature to

```
    public DataStore<? extends AbstractCriteria, ? extends AbstractResults, ? extends AbstractService> getResultsStore();
```

b) Add the type parameters to the class as a whole:

```
 abstract class AbstractSearchView<
     C extends AbstractCriteria,
     R extends AbstractResults,
     S extends AbstractService>
  public abstract DataStore<C, R, S> getResultsStore();
 } 
 class TravelSearchView extends AbstractSearchView<
     TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService> {
   ...
 }
```

The issue is that `DataStore<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService>` is *not* a subtype of `DataStore<AbstractCriteria, AbstractResults, AbstractService>`, even if those generic type arguments are respectively subtypes.

Comment: That was simply a typo, void should not have been there at all.  I didn't copy out of production code, but wrote by hand here in SO.

Comment: The problem is that Eclipse indicates an error in the child class:  The return type is incompatible with AbstractSearchView.getResultsStore()

Comment: Updated to respond to the new question.

Comment: Excellent!   "A" was the solution I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Your `AbstractSearchView` class needs to specify generic parameters for each of the parameters of `DataStore` if you want to override `getResultsStore()` with a different return type.

```
public abstract class AbstractSearchView<C extends AbstractCriteria, R extends AbstractResults, S extends AbstractService> {
    DataStore<AbstractCriteria, AbstractResults, AbstractService> resultsStore;
    public abstract DataStore<AbstractCriteria, AbstractResults, AbstractService> getResultsStore();
}

public class TravelSearchView extends AbstractSearchView<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService> {
    DataStore<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService> resultsStore;
    public DataStore<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService> getResultsStore() {
        return resultsStore;
    }
}
```

The supertype bounds (`X extends SomeClass`) in the parameters of `AbstractSearchView` ensures that subclasses of `AbstractSearchView` may only use subtypes of each of those parameters.

Comment: Excellent, great answer.  This will work for future development.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do it is to make a base class ( or interface ) generic:

```
public abstract class AbstractSerachView<
    TCriteria extends AbstractCriteria>,
    TResults extends AbstractResults,
    TService extends AbstractService>
{
    DataStore<TCriteria, TResults, TService> resultsStore;
    public DataStore<TCriteria, TResults, TService> getResultsStore()
    {
        return resultsStore;
    }
}
```

Then in implementation just provide concrete types

```
public class TravelSearchView
    extends AbstractSearchView<TravelCriteria, TravelResults, TravelService>
{
}
```

Also, as you can see, implementation class does not need to override `getResultsStore` method.

Comment: Thanks!  Great, clear answer.  This is a shorter lighter response than overriding the implementing method and works.